I initialized firebase for user auth and other functions in my flutter app and it's returning some errors I don't understand
This is the error being returned. I already initialized flutter clean and flutter run still returned same thing.
I tried Flutter clean and flutter run, all went to no avail.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\SideQuest-Mark-I\android\build.gradle' (C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\7.6.3\scripts\a1zch7hw5cne86vs0989xqvgz).
   > Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s


Hey, delete the C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches folder and try building again. Might be the case that some other process, is reading this file and hence blocks your build.

That error almost certainly doesn't have anything to do with the code in your app.
